# The tag g:include is not passing the model to the view correctly

Tags: grails

I have been struggling with these for a few hours now, and have come to the conclusion that it may be a bug with the 2.0.0.RC1.

At first I thought it was the project I was working on, but then I created a complete new project and was able to recreate the bug. Am using grails 2.0.0.RC1.

The bug presents itself when I try to include a model object in a GSP, for example:

### /hello/index.gsp

```
 <p>This data is coming from the model:</p>
 <p>content: ${content}</p>
 <g:include model="${otherModel}" view="/hello/include.gsp" />
```

Now in my action I have something like:

### HelloController.groovy

```
package helloworld

class HelloController {

        def index() {

    def model = [:]
    model.content = 'content...'

    def includeModel = [:]
    includeModel.content = 'includeModel...'

    model.otherModel = includeModel

    render( view:'index', model:model )
    }
}
```

The /hello/include.gsp file contains the following:

### /hello/include.gsp

```
<p>This data is coming from the included model:</p>
<p>content: ${content}</p>
```

But, what shows up on the page is not what I am expecting, this is what shows on the page:

### http://localhost:8080/helloworld/hello/index

```
This data is coming from the model:
content: content...
This data is coming from the included model:
content: content...
```

Any ideas? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
-Cesar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a bug, but according to the docs, the include tag is specifically designed to include the response of another controller/action or view in the current response -- not just additional GSPs. If you want to "include" another GSP into your page, you really should use the render tag. I have verified that your code works correctly with the render tag and renaming `include.gsp` to `_include.gsp` and making the tag be `<g:render model="${otherModel}" template="include" />`. I got the following output:

> This data is coming from the model:
>
> content: content...
>
> Using g:render: 
>   This data is coming from the included model:
>
> content: includeModel...

I also tried adding another action to the controller to return the included content and render include.gsp, and then using the g:include tag to output that in the page and it worked:

```
def include() {
    def includeModel = [:]
    includeModel.content = 'includeModel...'
    includeModel      
}
```

And then in the index.gsp I added:

```
<g:include action="include"/>
```

And I got:

> This data is coming from the model:
>
> content: content...
>
> Using g:render:
>   This data is coming from the included model:
>
> content: includeModel...
>
> Using g:include with action
>   This data is coming from the included model:
>
> content: includeModel...

Also, you don't have to specify render(view:'viewname, ...) in your controller if the view is the same name as the method in the controller. You can just return the model and it Grails will automatically pick the GSP file with the same name as the controller action.

All that being said, it still seems like what you're trying to do with the include tag should work, and I can't explain why it's not (and the source code for the tag isn't showing up at the bottom of the docs like it's supposed to either). I'd recommend filing a JIRA though if the render tag isn't an option for you.

Comment: I will try your recommendation. I was just hoping I didn't need to refactor all of those includes in our web application, because I was thinking of option you mentioned about calling the controller action. But, this was working prior to upgrading to 2.0.0.RC1.

Comment: I ended up taking your advise. And refactored all of the usages of g:include to g:render. Thanks for the recommendation. I've also raised this issue in the grails user mailing list, hopefully there will be a better answer there at some point.

Comment: It might warrant a JIRA even. It still seems like the model being passed in the tag attribute should override the containing page's model. At least the refactoring worked in the meantime!

Comment: I created [JIRA ticket GRAILS-8278](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8278) for this and it got fixed for version 2.0-RC2.